# Media library is not retrieving images

Tags: php, laravel, media, laravel-medialibrary

Iam using Laravel spatie media library backage in my project:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction

The media library shows null when trying to retrieve an image from a model using the code

```
$template->getMedia('templates')
```

Her is the Template.php model

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;


class Template extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory,InteractsWithMedia;
    protected $guarded =[];




    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->width(130)
            ->height(130);
    }

    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('templates');
    }

}
```

this the media table:
[image]

and here is the blade bage where I wont retrive the images

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Template::all() as $template)
 @foreach($template->getMedia('templates') as $key => $image)
<img src="{{$image->getUrl()}}">
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

I tried

```
dd($template->getMedia('templates'))
```

but it shows null items

can any one help?